# How would the Pusey-Barrett-Rudolph (PBR) theorem work in an $\psi$-ontic model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, foundations

In the PBR-Theorem they try to prove that $\psi$-epistemic models of quantum theory are impossible. The argument goes something like this:
Suppose we have two nonorthogonal states
\begin{equation}|\psi\rangle=|\uparrow\rangle \text{  and  } |\phi\rangle=|+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow\rangle+|\downarrow\rangle) \end{equation} in two identical physical systems. The combined system then is in one of these physical states \begin{aligned}
& \left|\omega_1\right\rangle_{12}=|\uparrow\rangle_1 \otimes|\uparrow\rangle_2 \\
& \left|\omega_2\right\rangle_{12}=|\uparrow\rangle_1 \otimes|+\rangle_2 \\
& \left|\omega_3\right\rangle_{12}=|+\rangle_1 \otimes|\uparrow\rangle_2 \\
& \left|\omega_4\right\rangle_{12}=|+\rangle_1 \otimes|+\rangle_2.
\end{aligned} Then, there exists a measurement that projects onto the basis vectors \begin{aligned}
& \left|\chi_1\right\rangle_{12}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\uparrow\rangle_1 \otimes|\downarrow\rangle_2+|\downarrow\rangle_1 \otimes|\uparrow\rangle_2\right) \\
& \left|\chi_2\right\rangle_{12}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\uparrow\rangle_1 \otimes|-\rangle_2+|\downarrow\rangle_1 \otimes|+\rangle_2\right) \\
& \left|\chi_3\right\rangle_{12}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|+\rangle_1 \otimes|\downarrow\rangle_2+|-\rangle_1 \otimes|\uparrow\rangle_2\right) \\
& \left|\chi_4\right\rangle_{12}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|+\rangle_1 \otimes|-\rangle_2+|-\rangle_1 \otimes|+\rangle_2\right)
\end{aligned} for which we can easily calculate that \begin{aligned}
& \left\langle\omega_1 \mid \chi_1\right\rangle=0 \\
& \left\langle\omega_2 \mid \chi_2\right\rangle=0 \\
& \left\langle\omega_3 \mid \chi_3\right\rangle=0 \\
& \left\langle\omega_4 \mid \chi_4\right\rangle=0 .
\end{aligned} PBR conclude from this that $\psi$-epistemicism is wrong, but i dont understand why. Where exactly is the premise of $\psi$-epistemicism mathematically implemented in the theorem. And why does an ontic model not have the same conclusion? I would like to understand how the theorem would play out in an ontic model.\
I know this is related to overlapping probability distributions in the ontic state space. But i guess i dont understand where exactly the overlap is contradicted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extract you have shown *is* the $\psi$-ontic model. The $\psi$-epistemic model is described in the preceding paragraphs of [Pusey, Barrett, & Rudolph](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.3328v1.pdf).

The interpretation of the quantum wavefunction $|\psi\rangle$ can be categorized as either $\psi$-ontic if "every complete physical state or ontic state in the theory is consistent with only one pure quantum state" and $\psi$-epistemic "if there exist ontic states that are consistent with more than one pure quantum state." (From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pusey%E2%80%93Barrett%E2%80%93Rudolph_theorem).)

PBR consider an experiment where we can prepare a system in one of two ways, leading (according to quantum mechanics) to pure quantum states $|\uparrow\rangle$ and $|+\rangle$ respectively. The real ontic state is labelled $\lambda$ and is allowed to include components not described by quantum mechanics.

The $\psi$-epistemic model has situations where preparations of *both* pure states can lead to the *same* real, ontic state. This is assumed to happen with at least non-zero probability $q$.

The figure below illustrates this. We have two systems that we can prepare either as $|\uparrow\rangle$ (top row) or $|+\rangle$ (bottom row) independently. Shading indicates where these correspond to real ontic states corresponding to the columns in the two tables. (Each block shown can represent many possible columns/states.) There will be some real states that can only arise when prepared as $|\uparrow\rangle$, and some real states that can only arise from $|+\rangle$, and if the $\psi$-epistemic model is valid, some that can arise from either. These occur with probability $q$.

[image]

Then the measurement apparatus makes a joint measurement of both states. It is assumed that the behaviour of the apparatus depends only on the actual ontic states $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ of the two systems, post-preparation. It does not know how they were prepared. Thus, there is a probability $q^2$ that *both* systems will be in a state such that the measurement apparatus cannot know which pure state was prepared. Whatever answer it picks, there will be a non-zero probability that, given the preparation methods, this outcome is *impossible*, with zero probability. It will therefore violate the predictions of quantum mechanics some of the time.

If the predictions of quantum mechanics are correct, then $q$ must be zero, and the pure quantum state is a real property of $\lambda$. For any given ontic state $\lambda$, it has a well-defined pure quantum state $\psi$.

The section you quote sets out the predictions of quantum mechanics, asserting that the probability of certain combinations of set-up and outcome are impossible. In the $\psi$-ontic case, they are. In the $\psi$-epistemic case, they can't be - thus the $\psi$-epistemic model contradicts these zero probability predictions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation, i think i understand it now a lot better! 
For clarification: The measurement device measures what preparation could impossibly have been prepared prior to the measurement, e.g. if i measure |X_1> (see above), the pointer will show "not |up>|up>" because this could not possibly have been the prepared state. If we assume overlap, at least sometimes the device will show a impossible result, because it will randomly point on one of the measurement outcomes, which might be orthogonal to the prepared state? Sorry if I am a bit slow here

Comment: Yes, that's the intention. Because the measurement device only sees the **real** state, it can't reliably determine the quantum state prepared in the epistemic case (so the pointer labels are a bit misleading). It has to do something (the measurement gives a complete set of basis states), but every answer will be wrong (according to QM) some of the time. If the real state *implies* the quantum state so the measurement device can give the right answer, that implies the quantum state is ontic.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for your very helpful explanations :)!